# Group policy not applying to new win7 box

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I just took delivery of a new desktop from Dell with win7 pro preinstalled. I removed the preinstalled dell crapware and then installed the software I really needed, ran updates and joined my domain. To my surprise I found that the group policy settings that customized my the home page to the company intranet did not apply.

It's strange because I had just created a new win7 VM and installed the OS from scratch. After the domain join, the homne page was set by group policy as normal. I really haven't changed this GP setting in a few years and it has always worked without a hitch.

I guess the next time I get a new box from Dell I'll format the HD and install Windows from scratch. That's not a great option right now because I've already installed all of my apps.

Anybody know how I can debug this and possibly get these GPOs working without a full reinstall?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try running:

```
gpupdate /force
```

from the command line, or perhaps:

```
rsop
```

to run the Resultant Set of Policy tool which will allow you to examine the GPOs that are being applied.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Resultant Set of Policy.

Verify that the computer is in the correct OU to get the GPO pushed to it.

Run `gpupdate /force`

Look in the eventvwr for failed GPO settings.

Answer (score 1):

Use RSOP and gpresult to debug the issue.

Comment: I ran RSOP and got an "Invalid Namespace" error on the physical box that had the problem, but no error on the VM which did have the policy